# Writing CLGeocoder result to Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Need a bit of help with Swift and Firebase.

This code, in getFriendlyLocation.swift ...

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore


class getfriendlyLocation: NSObject {

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var placemark: CLPlacemark!
    var countryCode: String!
    
    var db: Firestore!

    func initfriendlyLocation(lat:Double, lng:Double) {
        
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            self.processResponse(withPlacemarks: placemarks, error: error)
            
            self.db.collection("main").addDocument(data: ["Country":"US"]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("OK")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...produces error "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" at the addDocument() line.

The exact same code block works just fine outside the closure.

processResponse block doesn't do anything right now, just checks if it get values back or not, which it does.

I call getfriendlyLocation from ViewController.swift

```
var friendlyLoc = getfriendlyLocation()
friendlyLoc.initfriendlyLocation(lat: lat, lng: lng)
```

What is different when this code block is inside closure vs outside?

Thanks!

Adding...

```
func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR")

        } else {           
            print("OK")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to show `processResponse`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `db` variable is nil. You must do `self.db = Firestore.firestore()` before you use it. You can put it anywhere before your addDocument call.